# Creating a fixed background object in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

In three.js, I have created a yellow sphere to represent the sun. I would like the sun to remain fixed in the same relative position in the sky as the camera moves.

Right now, the sun remains in the same spot when you move. I created a version of it where the sun moves with the camera, but the sun will move in front of other objects.

I would like the sun to remain in the background, behind all other objects; and remain in the same camera position as a move.

[**Here**](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/rotating-cube/5997763341189120) is a link to the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and intuitive solution is to move the sun far into the sky and let the scene's perspective take care of it.
(Note this may be inefficient. See other answer for an alternative.)

For example:

```
// increase sun size to compensate the distance
var sungeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15.875, 12, 12 );
sun.position.y=200;
sun.position.z=-200;
```

You will see that the sun moves very little against the camera but stays realistically in the back of the scene. You can experiment with the size and distance to get the effect you want.

Comment: this is not a good approach for something like this because you have to unnecessarily extend the extents of your frustum, which can lead to precision issues. This is on top of there being parallax.

Answer (score 1):

On your sun do this

```
mySun.material.depthWrite = false; // to disable writing to the depth buffer
mySun.renderOrder = -999; // to draw the sun before any other stuff
```

The first line takes care of the sun being drawn "infinitely far away" from an ordering standpoint ie. stuff that gets drawn after the sun, will be drawn in front of it, regardless if they are  actually in front or not.

The second line should take care of the sun being drawn first (but you probably want to draw it after a skybox). By default all objects have renderOrder == 0.

At this point, the sun should render  "behind" everything, but it may still move, change size, and seem like its not infinitely far away.

The next thing you have to do is to make sure that the sun follows your camera and appears infinitely far away in actual perspective. You do this by having it follow the cameras position, but not rotation. You could put the sun in a container, and then copy the cameras position into the containers position at every tick. You can position the sun object within that container (it's relative to the camera), as long as its not clipped (between your near and far) it will work.